# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) after do-release-upgrade to 20.04 from 19.10

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I have:

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-33-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Pentium® CPU 4415U @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 11,5 GiB of RAM

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) after do-release-upgrade to 20.04 from 19.10

I have tried:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i polar-bookshelf
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/polar-bookshelf.* /tmp
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available 
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo sh -c 'for i in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages; do dpkg --merge-avail "$i"; done'
sudo apt-get clean
```

With no luck.

EDIT: I also had a problem with an icon package, I installed it and now I get:

```
package failed to install error while instaling package: tying to overwrite'/usr/lib/gnome-initial-setup/vendor.conf', which is also in package gnome-initial-setup 3.36.2-0ubuntu1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /path/to/offending.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1588098421~20.04~520c0fb_amd64.deb
```

Then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Did the trick